# Allow brackets in regex pattern

Tags: regex

I want to allow `[]` these brackets in a name field using regex. Please help me on this.

Comment: Just do not restrict the input at all.

Comment: but i also want to retrict user from entering characters such as #,*,&,$ etc.

Comment: i am facing a problem with these brackets only....

Comment: Where is the problem? Where is the regex you are using? How is it used (what language, method, etc?) Check the [MCVE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `/^([a-zA-Z '.`"\\:;_(){}<>-]*)?(s\/o|S\/O|w\/o|W\/O|d\/o|D\/O)?([a-zA-Z '.`"\\:;_(){}<>-]*)$/i` this is the regex i am using..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just escape them using `\`:

```
\[
\]
```

Comment: yeah its working....Thank you!!!!

Comment: @SurajChougule If you found it useful consider http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow